# French character display on xaml page

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I have some special characters in my French content. When i see the characters in XAML code, i can see the proper text in visual studio. But while running, the text is not getting rendered properly.

For example: `<TextBlock xml:lang="fr-CA" Foreground="Black" Text="Bay Nº doit contenir uniquement caractères alphabétiques ou numériques"/>`

In the given text, the underscore which we can see after N and below o is missing while running on the page.

Has anyone faced this issue/does anyone have any idea on resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

So I think what you're running into is an issue between ordinal and numero in which case a workaround would be to just implement the Numero unicode hex directly as the character set instead of translating a single ordinal.

Numero hex : `&#x2116;`

Shown as example which should render as desired both in designer and at runtime;

[image]

Hope this helps, cheers!